# Delete Row from Table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am developing an IOS app. Delete the row in tableview and data load in core data in table view. When Click the delete button App crash.
    Reason is reason: `Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (18) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (18), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)...`

_fetchedobj is an NSArray to Fetch data from core data

```
//Code is
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return _fetchedobj.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }
    data = [_fetchedobj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        NSManagedObject *managedObject = [_fetchedobj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
        [myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [myTable endUpdates];
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your implementation of `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` look like?

Comment: Should you not be doing `[_fetchedobj removeAtIndex:indexPath.row]` in the delete? Otherwise you did not update the data model used to determine the number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you forget to remove this object from your datasource array?

try repopulate your `_fetchedobj` because you must configure your model after deletion. For more detail, read https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html

Try this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        NSManagedObject *managedObject = [_fetchedobj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
        // insert this line to your code

        NSMutableArray *newA = [_fetchedobj mutableCopy ];
        [newA removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
        _fetchedobj = newA;

        [myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [myTable endUpdates];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this line for deleting row of table view

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```